# When click D drive: Application Not Found

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, check-disk

I wanna make some space in my D drive. Just 648 mb of free space and the disk have 117GB.
I click properties, "Tools" tab, and "Check now" button. That was during too long, so I cancel it. But when I was going to click the drive to find something, it showed me the error "The disk check could not be performed because windows can't access the disk"."

I restarted the pc and try to open, and now is says: "D:\ Application Not Found".

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you catched some virus. Try to install/run some antivitus software. Faster way will be to right click on your hard drive -> open, and try to find autorun.inf file and then delete it